# Is Boost.Phoenix inherently slower than the equivalent C++11 lambdas (does it use virtual calls, 'volatile' usage, etc.)?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, boost, lambda, boost-phoenix

I always thought Boost.Phoenix used type-inference to infer everything statically, until I tried this code:

```
#include <vector>
#include <boost/phoenix/phoenix.hpp>

using namespace boost::phoenix;
using namespace boost::phoenix::placeholders;

struct Foo { int x; };

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> bar;
    bind(&Foo::x, ref(bar)[_1])("invalid index");   // oops
    return 0;
}
```

and got the warning:

> warning C4239: nonstandard extension used : 'argument' : conversion from `const char [3]` to `volatile const boost::proto::detail::anyns::any &`
>          A non-const reference may only be bound to an lvalue

That surprised me. I didn't expect to see `any` anywhere, much less `volatile`!

Does that mean Boost.Phoenix is therefore actually inherently slower than its equivalent C++11 lambdas (ignoring the particular compiler I'm using here)?

Answer (score 2):

It's not `Boost.Any`, it's `any` from `Boost.Proto` implementation details - please see `boost/proto/detail/decltype.hpp` . It has zero run-time overhead.

Comment: +1 thanks for pointing that out. What about `volatile` though?

Answer (score 0):

I would expect Boost.Phoenix to be slower than the equivalent C++11 lambda. The `bind` function takes the address of a function to call later on, so the compiler would have a much harder time inlining the resulting function call than if a lambda were used that directly called the required function.

The overhead that I am referring to here is the overhead of an indirect call to a function, a Sufficiently Smart Compiler could remove it, but I'm not sure if any compiler actually does this for of Boost.Phoenix.